# HTML dropdown list not returning Python module in Flask route

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, flask

I have two scripts that end in dataframes loaded into my `app.py`. The dropdown lists in my first HTML page are the column names of both dataframes. When clicking submit, I'm trying to route the selections to a third module `regrplot` in `app.py`. This module would use the selection to determine the dataframes, join the two on the year column, and run a regression plot image generator.

Error I'm getting: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y1' referenced before assignment`

When getting to the `dropdown.html` page. I am able to see the dropdown lists populated, as well as the submit button.

Variables with `df` in their name, are dataframes imported from other modules.

```
dropdown.html

  <body>
    <form name="var1" action="/dropdown_x">
       <fieldset>
          <legend>Table Variable 1</legend>
          <p>
             <label>Select</label>
             <select name="df_variable1">
                {% for each in dropdown_fields %}
                  <option value="{{each}}">{{each}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
          </p>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
    <form name = "var2" action="/dropdown_y">
        <fieldset>
           <legend>Table Variable 2</legend>
           <p>
              <label>Select</label>
              <select name="df_variable2">
                 {% for each in dropdown_fields %}
                   <option value="{{each}}">{{each}}</option>
                 {% endfor %}
                 </select>
           </p>
        </fieldset>
        <button><input name="regrplt" method="GET" action="/regrplot" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  value="Submit"></button>     
     </form>

  </body>
```

```
app.py

import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

book_fields= list(book_data.year_book_data)
census1_fields = list(censusLoad.df_full1)
census2_fields = list(censusLoad.df_full2)
dropdown_fields = book_fields + census1_fields + census2_fields



@app.route("/dropdown")
def dropdownList():
    return render_template('dropdown.html', dropdown_fields=dropdown_fields)


@app.route("/dropdown_x", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testt1():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df_variable1 = request.form['df_variable1']

        if df_variable1 in book_fields:
           x1 = book_data.df_yearbook
        if df_variable1 in census1_fields:
           x1 = censusLoad.df_full1
        if df_variable1 in census2_fields:
           x1 = censusLoad.df_full2


    return x1

@app.route("/dropdown_y", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testt2():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        df_variable2 = request.form['df_variable2']

        if df_variable2 in book_fields:
           y1 = book_data.df_year_book
        if df_variable2 in census1_fields:
           y1 = censusLoad.df_full1
        if df_variable2 in census2_fields:
           y1 = censusLoad.df_full2

    return y1




@app.route("/regrplot", methods=['GET','POST'])
def regrplot():
    if request.method == 'POST':

# Have tried with and without this block
        df_variable1 = request.form['df_variable1']
        df_variable2 = request.form['df_variable2']

        if df_variable1 in book_fields:
            x1 = book_data.df_yearbook
        if df_variable1 in census1_fields:
            x1 = censusLoad.df_full1
        if df_variable1 in census2_fields:
            x1 = censusLoad.df_full2

        if df_variable2 in book_fields:
            y1 = book_data.df_yearbook
        if df_variable2 in census1_fields:
            y1 = censusLoad.df_full1
        if df_variable2 in census2_fields:
            y1 = censusLoad.df_full2
#

        Reg_df = x1.merge(y1, how = "inner", left_on ='year', right_on = 'year')
        plot = sns.regplot(x=f'{df_variable1}', y=f'{df_variable2}', data = Reg_df)
        plot.savefig('regrplot', format='png')

    return render_template("regression.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
regression.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <title>formDemo.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <image src="regrplot.png"></image>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What the point of having `/dropdown_x` and `/dropdown_y` endpoints? Are they not actually needed for `/regrplot`?

Comment: New to `flask` so I'm not sure if I'm using the decorator correctly here. However, the functions that define the `dropdown_(x,y)` routes , are meant to return the `dfs` for the `.merge()` method of `pandas` in  `/regrplot` . The `df_variables` from the selected form data are also meant to provide the variables for `.regplot()` in `plot`. The commented line shows where I have tried with it in and out of the `.regplot()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but try these fixes:

Option 1: The forms need to be set to POST in order to use the "request.form" method, otherwise use the "request.args" method instead (GET).  This is why I believe you have the error where "y1" isn't defined because the "request.method == 'POST'" condition is False, thus the "y1" was never declared.  Should be the same for "x1".

```
<form name="var1" action="/dropdown_x" method="post">
```

Option 2: If you're using GET, then try checking for "GET" instead of "POST":

```
if request.method == 'GET':
  df_variable1 = request.args['df_variable1']
```

Make sure you're using "request.args.get('df_variable1') or "request.args['df_variable1']" because "request.form[]" only works for "POST".

For best practice, you should declare "x1" and "y1" in case the condition is false, in which case "x1" and "y1" will be undefined.

Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the `regrplot` function is running, but I'm getting an error on my return. `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a DataFrame.`

Going to play with the return and see if I can fix this